# Galaxy S5 apk android file transfer not working

Tags: android, apk, galaxy

I need to install an `.apk` file on my galaxy s5 using Android File Transfer. Since there is no Apk directory as in LG, I place the apk in the Download directory. But on the phone itself, when I go to `My Files > Download` the apk is not there. Does anyone know how to accomplish this with S5?

Comment: why the single vote to close? This is an android development question. The only way to test a signed apk is by installing it "manually" through the `Android File Transfer` not through eclipse. If I use eclipse then I end up with a debug apk. I am using a mac. Perhaps the voter does not understand android development.